# Voltar para Página Anterior quando der Erro

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, tenho um código de cadastro de email Newsletter e ao colocar email errado ou der algum erro, gostaria que ao invés de redirecionar para a página cadastro.html, ele redirecionasse para a página anterior, como posso fazer isso?

O Código PHP está assim:

```
    <?php
include("config.php");
$email  = $_POST["e-mail"];
$opcao  = $_POST["opcao"];
$codigo = md5($email);
if($email == ""){
echo "<script>alert('Por favor, digite um email válido.');";
echo "location.href='cadastro.html'</script>";
} [..]
```

Não sei se pode ser feito em JS ou apenas em PHP mesmo.

Agradeço a todos só por tentarem ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que a melhor forma seria usando o PHP.

```
if ($email === '') {

    header('location: /index.php');
    exit;
}
```

Lembrando que, para utilizar essa forma, é necessário que nenhum conteúdo seja enviado para o browser, pelo php, antes dessa declaração.

Se você quiser pegar a página anterior pelo PHP, você pode usar a variável `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, que tratá a url da página de origem do acesso.

```
 header(sprintf('location: %s', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
 exit;
```

Em alguns casos, essa variável não existirá, pois não haverá a url de origem, por talvez de tratar de uma requisição feita diretamente à essa url.

Então, você pode usar um fallback.

```
$fallback = 'index.php';

$anterior = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : $fallback;

header("location: {$anterior}");
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$email  = $_POST["e-mail"];
$opcao  = $_POST["opcao"];
$codigo = md5($email);
if($email == ""){
echo "<script>alert('Por favor, digite um email válido.');";
echo "javascript:history.go(-1)'</script>";
} [..]
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu sei que o problema é antigo, ainda assim vou deixar uma resposta como opção, caso alguém precise.

```
<?php
//Função para redirecionar a página para o link
function redireciona($link){
     if ($link==-1){
     echo" <script>history.go(-1);</script>";
     }else{
     echo" <script>document.location.href='$link'</script>";
     }
 };
//Cria uma variavel
$link = 'minhapagina.php';

//E aonde quiser chama a função dentro de um if ou qualquer coisa.

// Chama a função
redireciona($link); 
?>
```